# Differentiate $x^e+e^x=z$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

While integrating, I got an example something just like this.
$$\int \frac{e^{e-1}+e^{x-1}}{x^e+e^x}\ \mathrm dx$$

Let,
$$x^e+e^x=z$$
$$ex^{e-1}\ \mathrm dx+e^x\ \mathrm dx=\mathrm dz$$
$$\mathrm dx\ (ex^{e-1}+e^x)=\mathrm dz$$

That's what I got. But, my book wrote that.

$$x^e+e^x\implies(x^{e-1}+e^{x-1})\ \mathrm dx=\frac{1}{e}\ \mathrm dz$$
Did I differentiate wrong? When differentiating $e^x$, it forever remains constant. But, how they got the value ($e$)?

[image]

If the book is wrong than, how can I integrate that equation (the first equation)?

Comment: I think your book is wrong.

Comment: $e^x=e.e^{x-1}$

Comment: You initially had a typo in your post where @Jhuma correctly concluding the book was wrong. However, the picture proves the book was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book isn't wrong. Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, \begin{align*}
ex^{e-1}+e^x&=\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}x}\\
x^{e-1}+e^{x-1}&= \frac1e\cdot \frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}x}\\
(x^{e-1}+e^{x-1}){\rm d}x&= \frac1e{\rm d}z
\end{align*}

Comment: Ohh! Sorry! Than, that's my mistake... I had did typo mistake in question...